# incompatible types: Staff can not be converted to CustomerServiceRep

Tags: netbeans

I am encountering a problem with my code to link login form to my csr form to redirect staff to the correct form. i have a Staff class and a CustomerServiceRep class with the CustomerServiceRep extends to Staff. the code is

```
        //staff object to store staff logged in successfully
         Staff emp = null; 

         /*Use core to store staff logged in should return an staff
         object if username/password found OR null if credentials invalid*/

         emp = core.login(username, password);

         if (emp==null){//staff not found

              //display feedback 
         pop.showMessageDialog(
             null,
             "Login Credentials Invalid",
             "Errors",
             JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
         );
         }else{//staff found, redirect to dashboard

             pop.showMessageDialog(
             null,
             "Login Successful",
             "Feedback",
             JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE
         );
             //redirect user to appropriate dashboard
             if(emp.getRole().equals("csr")){
                 //go to csr dash

                 //hide the login form(current form)
                 this.setVisible(false);

                /**create new instance of AdminDashboard form and
                 * pass the instance of Staff (emp) who
                 * has logged in successfully
                 */ 
                 Z_Frm_CSR CSRDash = new Z_Frm_CSR(emp);

                 //Show CSR Dashboard
                 CSRDash.setVisible(true);

             }
```

I am getting the error "incompatible types: Staff can not be converted to CustomerServiceRep" at for emp

```
                 Z_Frm_CSR CSRDash = new Z_Frm_CSR(emp);
```

I am new to this site and fairly new to coding i dont know if i provided enough information on my error please ask for more information if not given.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an explicit cast, as your Z_Frm_CSR constructor likely uses an explicit type in it's declaration (CustomerServiceRep) and not the base class (Staff) or a generified type (T extends Staff).

So: `Z_Frm_CSR CSRDash = new Z_Frm_CSR((CustomerServiceRep)emp);`

Comment: well not im getting an exception error : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: athenas.garden.system.Staff cannot be cast to athenas.garden.system.CustomerServiceRep

Comment: In that case the object really IS a Staff object (that wasn't clear from your code) and not a CustomerServiceRep object. If the class really needs a CustomerServiceRep object then it needs to be that object type. If it can ALSO be a Staff object, change the constructor so it can take a Staff object or add a constructor that takes a Staff object. Java will not automagically convert types for you.

Comment: i changed my CustomerServiceRep emp = null to staff and it works now Thanks for the help